# How to store a value in a cookie and then echo it

Tags: php, forms, cookies

I looked at similar questions but still it doesn't work.

What I'm trying to do is, for example, the user inputs his name/city and I want this data to be stored in a cookie and next time he enters the page it shows the message `"Hello [name] from [city]."`

I tried doing

```
$_COOKIE['name']=$_POST['name'];
after the form and at the beginning I put
if(!empty($_COOKIE['name']))
echo "Hello" . $_COOKIE['name'];
```

Anyway, the code is a bit larger than that but basically that's what I'm trying to do. Nothing shows up. Yes, I used setcookie after I verified that the user completed every input with if(!empty($_POST)).

Comment: Are you using Angular or jQuery or something for cookies?

Comment: "Yes, I used setcookie" — Where? Provide a [mcve]

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS) User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Comment: "Also, if you could help me with something else, not really related to cookies" — If you have another question, then [ask another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Don't jam it on the end of something unrelated.  Also: Don't ask massively broad questions. Focus on specific problems.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry - didn't see PHP.  Only JS here.  Was only going to point you to 
 https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_cookie_username ... it still may be of some help anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*..Yes, I used setcookie*". But, It's Invisible (or type='hidden') in the code provided.

**Set Cookie**

```
/* Set Cookie */
$cookie_duration = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60; // Cookie Duration is for 30 Days. Change it accordingly.

setcookie ("_name", $_POST['name'], $cookie_duration);
setcookie ("_city", $_POST['city'], $cookie_duration);

/* Retreive Cookie */
$name = isset($_COOKIE["_name"]) ? $_COOKIE["_name"] : "";
$city = isset($_COOKIE["_city"]) ? $_COOKIE["_city"] : "";

if($name != "" && $city != ""){
  echo "Hello ".$name." from ".$city.".";
}
?>
```

**Unset Cookie**

```
<?php
/* If wanted to remove the cookie after some period of time,
 * Unset Cookie 
 */
setcookie("_name", "", time()-3600);
setcookie("_city", "", time()-3600);

?>
```

Comment: It all depends upon your code functionality @Phux. You have to share your code. Because, this is how cookie works. Now,it all depends upon your logic how you implemented it.

Comment: *No Problem* Glad, It Worked For You @Phux . Keep Coding.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use setcookie.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

`echo $_COOKIE['foo']` gives you the content of the cookie with the name 'foo'.

Do not use a single cookie for every value you need. Instead think about storing the data as JSON in one single data cookie.